# Adding a 3 variable data validation dropdown to a loop that creates a new workbook based on values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the below VBA to create new workbooks based on the  names of supervisors (in column D) but I'd like to also have a column in each of those workbooks with a data-validation dropdown that has 3 variables listed (1,2,3 for simplicity). Where/how would I include that in the below? Thank you!

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Split_Data_in_workbooks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim data_sh As Worksheet
Set data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim setting_Sh As Worksheet
Set setting_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")

Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet

''''' Get unique supervisors
setting_Sh.Range("A:A").Clear
data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
data_sh.Range("D:D").Copy setting_Sh.Range("A1")

setting_Sh.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Application.CountA(setting_Sh.Range("A:A"))

data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 4, setting_Sh.Range("A" & i).Value

Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)

data_sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy nsh.Range("A1")`
nsh.UsedRange.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15`

nwb.SaveAs setting_Sh.Range("H6").Value & "/" & setting_Sh.Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsx"
nwb.Close False
data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
Next i

setting_Sh.Range("A:A").Clear

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA and tried to input the below within my sequence but immediately received an error - the code makes sense to me, but i'm not sure the location it should be placed in

```
Sub DropDownListinVBA()

Range("E2").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                           AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                           Formula1:="1,2,3"

End Sub
```

Comment: " immediately received an error" - if you're seeing any errors with your code it's always useful to tell us exactly what error(s) you're getting, and on which line(s) of code.

Comment: No matter where i plug it in, i get an 'expected end sub' error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add that as a line in your main sub:

```vb
'...
nsh.UsedRange.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15
        
        nsh.Range("E2:E" & nsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Validation.Add _
                Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="1,2,3"
'...
```